# Singleton dependency injection for Android library

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm building a library that contains a few activities, and potentially could be integrated with a few different applications.

I'm using Dagger2 for the dependency injection, and I need to share some singletons between different controllers(i.e. database, retrofit, gson, etc.)

Since there is no guarantee that the host app will is using Dagger2 and I cannot customize the Application class.

What is the best way to emulate `ApplicationComponent` for the SDK?

Comment: I'll suggest you, remove third-party libraries from SDK as much as possible. Don't use DI with dagger, instead go fo manual [dependency injection.](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/manual) 

You can take reference [from this repo](https://github.com/happysingh23828/Dagger-2-Showcase/tree/manual_dependency_injection) which has implemented manual DI in a separate branch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but SDK contains many screens with UI, with manual DI - it will be very messy.